# What are the default Akka dispatcher configuration values?

Tags: java, scala, akka, dispatcher

In the Akka documentation it states that if a dispatcher is not configured a default dispatcher will be used. What are the properties of the default dispatcher i.e parallelism-min, parallelism-factor, parallelism-max etc. ?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

By default the dispatcher provided by `Akka` is one with a `fork-join-executor`, and the default parallelism values are these:

- **parallelism-min:** 8
- **parallelism-factor:** 3.0
- **parallelism-max:** 64

You can see all  of this in the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html).

There is a section named: **[Listing of the Reference Configuration](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html#Listing_of_the_Reference_Configuration)**

Here is the relevant part of the configuration file (I only removed the comments):

```
default-dispatcher {
    type = "Dispatcher"
    executor = "fork-join-executor"

    fork-join-executor {
        parallelism-min = 8
        parallelism-factor = 3.0
        parallelism-max = 64
    }

    thread-pool-executor {
        keep-alive-time = 60s
        core-pool-size-min = 8
        core-pool-size-factor = 3.0
        core-pool-size-max = 64
        max-pool-size-min = 8
        max-pool-size-factor  = 3.0
        max-pool-size-max = 64
        task-queue-size = -1
        task-queue-type = "linked"

        allow-core-timeout = on
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, somehow I missed that section.

Comment: @Tsume, could you select this answer as the correct one? Or at least tell me what it needs to be a more complete answer?