# Play WS request times out sooner than withRequestTimeout

Tags: scala, playframework, play-ws

I am making a web service request that produces a Future. Like so (a simplified reproduction):

```
import play.api.libs.ws.WSClient
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
class Service(wsClient: WSClient)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) {
  def callWebService() = {
    val req: WSRequest = wsClient.url(...).withRequestTimeout(180 seconds)...
    val respFuture:Future[Response] = req.execute()
  }
}
```

The web service being invoked gets 180 seconds to respond before WSClient gives up.

This Service class' client now calls it as `service.callWebService()`. When the third party web service takes > 120 seconds, instead of waiting for 180 seconds, the future timesout at 120 seconds (`java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Read timeout to localhost/127.0.0.1:8081 after 120000 ms` thrown in `application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3` thread).

Appreciate any pointers on how to increase the 120 seconds used by the default dispatcher to 180 seconds.

Note:

1. The app uses Akka actors elsewhere. But there are no actors involved in this control flow.
2. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16175725/what-are-the-default-akka-dispatcher-configuration-values) comes close but doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Play WS](https://github.com/playframework/play-ws/blob/master/play-ws-standalone/src/main/resources/reference.conf) includes a global request timeout, which defaults to 2 minutes.

Putting the following in your application's config (by default `application.conf`) should rectify things.

```
play.ws.timeout.request = 3 minutes
play.ws.timeout.idle = 3 minutes
```

Comment: Setting that config didn't help (same TimeoutException at 2 mins.).

Comment: But setting play.ws.timeout.idle did resolve the issue. Thank you @Levi Ramsey. I would appreciate it if you include this in your answer for future reference.